# How to write replace method in Ruby with gsub?

Tags: javascript, regex, ruby, gsub

So I have this function in JS and I want to write it in Ruby any idea guys ?

```
arr = "### ### Lorem.  "
arr.replace(/(#+) (.*)/g, (_, h, t) => `<h${h.length}>${t}</h${h.length}>`)
```

I am trying

```
arr.gsub( /(?<lvl>\#{1,6})(?<text>.*)/){ |m| "#{m[:lvl]} #{m[:text]}"}
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     8: from /Users/mereynurlan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'         
     7: from /Users/mereynurlan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/irb:23:in `load'         
     6: from /Users/mereynurlan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-
```

Comment: Please share the code that fails for you.

Comment: What do you mean?@WiktorStribiżew

Comment: If you are asking code that I have tried there are millions of them therefore I am here asking questions.

Comment: Here you go @WiktorStribiżew
```arr.gsub( /(?<lvl>\#{1,6})(?<text>.*)/){ |m| "#{m[:lvl]} #{m[:text]}"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
        8: from /Users/mereynurlan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        7: from /Users/mereynurlan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        6: from /Users/mereynurlan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-
```

Comment: Please add the full error stack trace to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
arr = arr.gsub(/(#+) (.*)/) { "<h#{$1.length}>#{$2}</h#{$1.length}>" }
```

See a [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/G5QRJ9)

The `(#+) (.*)` pattern is simple: it captures one or more hash chars into Group 1 and then matches a space and matches and captures the rest of the line into Group 2.

The `"<h#{$1.length}>#{$2}</h#{$1.length}>"` replacement is a double quoted string literal that allows string interpolation. `#{$1.length}>` and `#{$2}` are interpolated `$1.length` and `$2`, where `$n` refers to the captured substrings.

Comment: yeah, that was what I was missing I wrote it like `#{\2}` instead of `#{$2}`.